# I have uploaded WordPress and then getting 500 - Internal server error

Tags: php, wordpress, web-hosting

I have uploaded wordpress-4.1.1 on my server and my domain is http://www.daatcreations.com/ but getting **500 - Internal server error.**

I don't know why this problem occurs. What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: remove the .htaccess file. It might still be active and it seems you are on a windows server

Comment: yes i have window server.

Comment: .htaccess is already removed because i haven't seen it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of reasons why your site might be serving a 500 Error to your users but two are most common:

A Permissions Error. In most cases, a 500 Internal Server Error is due to an incorrect permission on one or more files or folders. In most of those cases, an incorrect permission on a PHP and CGI script is to blame. These should usually be set at 0775 (-rwxr-xr-x).

A PHP Timeout. If your script connects to external resources and those timeout, an HTTP 500 error can occur. Timeout rules, or better error handling in your script, should help if this is the cause of the 500 error.

A Coding Error in .htaccess. While not as common, be sure to check that your site's .htaccess file is properly structured.

Comment: Rajnikant bro .htaccess file is not exist in my server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable SELINUX. You can check the status by executing "sestatus". Open "/etc/selinux/config" and disable SELINUX like below.

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

save and reboot your system and try again.

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for the answer. Readers prefer it if answers do not contain signatures, straplines, or advertisements - just stick to answer material as much as possible. Thanks!